# Why my helloworld program can't run with command line '>java HelloWorld'?

Tags: java

I write a simple program using java language, then try to compile and run it on Windows console, the compile is ok, but when I try to run it with command line '>java HelloWorld', the console reports 'Error: Could not find or load main class', this is my code(c:\Sample\HelloWorld.java) as below:

```
package com.sample.test;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

If I comment out the line "package com.sample.test", try the compile and run command lines again, everything is ok, I can't understand why. Here is the environment variables in my computer:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;
CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
```

My question is if I still want to reserve the package declaration, how can I run my program?

Comment: Did you *compile* your code using `javac` at any point?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen what he said. Also, make sure you set the cmd to the location of your file. So like `cd C://Users//Me//Desktop` (if its on the desktop) then do `javac HelloWorld.java`. Finally do `java HelloWorld`. Also, just to ensure that your path is set correctly. Try typing `javac` in the cmd and make sure it shows a usage dialog thing with parameters and stuff rather then an error of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put your main class into a package, then you also have to give that package name when running it:

```
java com.sample.test.HelloWorld
```

And you have to make sure the class file can be found. You cannot run `java` from the directory that contains `HelloWorld.class`. You have to run it from the directory that contains the `com` folder (or adjust your classpath).